# How do typical Single page applications work?

Tags: web, single-page-application

I see a lot of websites where you can click a link and it changes the /url, however no traffic is sent (Checking the network tab), and the content changes. How do these work, and how could I implement this? I came across this on [this page](https://gren-lang.org/learn).

Comment: Also search for PWA - Progressive Web Application